# How to retrieve the column value as row value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we retrieve information to be a row information from column values?
For example, we have a table

```
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      ID   |     Field   |  FieldVlaue  |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      1    |     Name    |  Jack        |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      1    |     Country |  Australia   |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      1    |     PostCode|  0277        |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      2    |     Name    |  John        |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      2    |     address |  Wyard       |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
|      2    |  ContactNum |  1234567     |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|
```

Based on the above table, how can we get a table like below

```
|-----------|-------------|--------------|-------------|---------|-----------|
|      ID   |     Name    |  Country     | PostCode    |Address  | ContactNum|
|-----------|-------------|--------------|-------------|---------|-----------|
|      1    |     Jack    |  Australia   | 0277        |Null     | Null      |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|-------------|---------|-----------|
|      2    |     John    |  Null        | Null        | Wyard   |1234567
|-----------|-------------|--------------|-------------|---------|-----------|
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL to do this. I have tried CASE, but CASE will give duplicated IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use condition aggregation

```
select id,
       max(case when Field='Name' then FieldVlaue end) as Name,
       max(case when Field='Country' then FieldVlaue end) as Country,
       max(case when Field='PostCode' then FieldVlaue end) as PostCode,
       max(case when Field='Address' then FieldVlaue end ) as Address,
       max(case when Field='ContactNum' then FieldVlaue end) as ContactNum 
from t
group by id
```

Comment: what's the max here do?

Comment: I don't understand how will this ensure correct id is joined with names, country etc.

Comment: Every id have several field but only one `'Name'` so on the conditional aggregation everything `<> 'Name'` get the `NULL` as default result for case. you can write like this  `case WHEN Field='Name' THEN FieldVlaue ELSE NULL END)` and `MAX()` ignore null values

Comment: Hi Juan, just curious what if ID 1 can have more than 2 names ? for example ID1 has a name 'Jack' and another row with name 'Peter'. will this 'MAX()' still work?